# Eigenvalues and plot are very slow

Tags: plotting, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I'mt trying to find eigenvalues (and plot them) but the evaluation takes **way** too long. I don't think it supposed to be a complicated computations. What am I doing wrong?

```
n = 3;
mat1 = Table[E^(I α (x - 1)) KroneckerDelta[x, y], {x, 1, n}, {y, 1, n}];
mat2 = Table[E^(-I α (x - 1)) KroneckerDelta[x, y], {x, 1, n}, {y, 1, n}];
mat3 = Table[KroneckerDelta[x - 1, y], {x, 1, n}, {y, 1, n}];
mat4 = Table[KroneckerDelta[x + 1, y], {x, 1, n}, {y, 1, n}];
sigmap = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}};
sigmam = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}};
H = KroneckerProduct[mat1, sigmap] + KroneckerProduct[mat2, sigmam] 
    + E^(I k α) KroneckerProduct[mat2, sigmap]
    + E^(-I k α) KroneckerProduct[mat1, sigmam] 
    + KroneckerProduct[mat3, sigmap] + KroneckerProduct[mat4, sigmam];
energies = Eigenvalues[H] /. α -> Pi/701;
Plot[energies, {k, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: If you introduce a Machine Precision number it will go much faster, put `701.` instead of `701` in your substitution for instance.

Comment: The evaluation of `Eigenvalues` goes much quicker if you perform the alpha substitution before the call, thus making it a purely numeric eigenvalue probem instead of a symbolic one: `energies = Eigenvalues[H /. \[Alpha] -> Pi/701];`

Comment: they are both correct: `energies = Eigenvalues[H /. α -> Pi/701.]`

Comment: wow it's much better now, thanks. but i still have to run it for n=200 so any other advice you might have will be very useful.

Comment: If you have to deal with matrices that large, consider a `SparseArray[]` formulation: `mat1 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[Table[E^(I α (x - 1)), {x, 1, n}]]]; mat2 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[Table[E^(-I α (x - 1)), {x, 1, n}]]]; mat3 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n - 1], -1, n]]; mat4 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n - 1], 1, n]]; sigmap = SparseArray[{1, 2} -> 1, {2, 2}]; sigmam = SparseArray[{2, 1} -> 1, {2, 2}];`. `KroneckerProduct[]` will handle those automagically.

Comment: would something like `Hfunc = Function[{k, a, n},
   KroneckerProduct[mat1[a, n], sigmap] + 
    KroneckerProduct[mat2[a, n], sigmam] + 
    E^(I k a) KroneckerProduct[mat2[a, n], sigmap] + 
    E^(-I k a) KroneckerProduct[mat1[a, n], sigmam] + 
    KroneckerProduct[mat3[n], sigmap] + 
    KroneckerProduct[mat4[n], sigmam]
   ];` and `H = Function[{k}, Hfunc[k, Pi/701., n]]` and finally `energies = Compile[{{k, _Real}}, Eigenvalues[H[k]], {{_, _Real, 1}}]` help?

Comment: Also just realised there is still a symbolic `k` dependence, which is bad for performance. We can get rid of this by delaying the evaluation of `Eigenvalues` until we know the numeric value of `k` by wrapping it in a function: `MyEigenvalues[kk_?NumericQ] := 
 Sort@Eigenvalues[H /. {\[Alpha] -> Pi/701., k -> kk}];Plot[MyEigenvalues[k], {k, 0, 1000}]`

Comment: @user42582 Compilation doesn't have much effect on `Eigenvalues` (see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CompilingWolframLanguageExpressions.html) for a reference in the docs) but might be useful for constructing the matrix.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. i'm standing on ~25 secs for n=20 without suggested SparseArray and ~21 secs with SparseArray (is it possible that for different sizes it will be less efficient?)

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke: it overcomes the symbolic dependence on `k` even if the gains from compilation are negligible (which is something I haven't measured in this particular instance) although I do understand that using a `Function`/wrapper would achieve the same goal.

Comment: @user42582 Ah, haven't thought about the builtin `NumericQ` property of `Compile`. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @UP_TLV `Eigenvalues` is the main bottle neck of the computation and its computation time will scale up with higher `n`.

Answer (score 3):

**This answer is edited in order to provide a summary of the problem, the various strategies employed in tackling it and supply some statistics.**

The original problem had to do with time, ie it took too long to produce output:

```
energies = Eigenvalues[H] /. α -> Pi/701;
```

even for modest values of the underlying parameters (mainly `n`).

People in the comments suggested that the bottleneck was due to precision issues. Namely, **@KraZug** suggested to replace *701* with *701.* (see code segment above) while **@Thies Heidecke** opted for moving the `ReplaceAll` statement inside `Eigenvalues[]`. These suggestions aimed to 'force' the `Eigenvalues` *bult-in* to treat its input numerically, instead of symbolically.

At this point, it is worth the time to take a step back and contemplate on the *nature* of `H`. It is a $2n$ x $2n$ *parametric* matrix; its entries are, for the most part, complex (*parametric*) numbers and integer quantities (1 and 0). Indeed, forcing the entries of `H` to be numeric quantities would allow the *built-in* support for numeric calculations to kick-in. But neither suggestion fully achieved that end.

Consider the following example:

```
f[x_] := {x}
f[a] /. a -> 1.
```

The output of the last evaluation is `{1}` as we'd might probably expect **but** that is not what we needed. Tracing out the evaluation steps, `ReplaceAll[]` matches `a` only **after** the definition of `f` has been evaluated. That means, that when `f` acts upon its parameter (`f[a]`), `a`'s value is still *symbolic* not numeric.

Also, evaluating `f[a /. a -> 1]` again produces `{1}`,only this time, the evaluation of `f`'s argument is performed in *integer* terms. Perhaps the output of `f[ a / 2 /. a -> 1]` and `f[ a / 2 /. a -> 1.]` is more enlightening. In the later case, `f` acts upon its input,after it has been transformed into a *numeric* quantity (`{0.5}`) while in the former it returns `{1/2}`.

On a separate note, **@J.M.** suggested in the comments to use `SparseArray[]` in order to tackle the problem of high dimensionality (`n=200`). That was the intended use-case of the original question's code. In my orignal answer, and for my original solution, after using `SparseAray[]`, I stumbled upon *Mathematica*'s notice that the calculation of `Eigenvalues[]` "...is likely to be faster with dense matrix methods, the sparse input matrix will be converted".

Additionaly, **@Thies Heidecke** pointed out that my using `Compile[]` was unlikely to provide significant advantages outside from, perhaps, speeding up the construction of the original matrices (inputs). An additional insight was that in the original code, matrix `H` was dependent on the *symbolic* parameter `k`. The workaround was sought in wrapping the calculations of `Eigenvalues[H]` in a function that allowed only numeric input (eg `MyEigenvalues[kk_?NumericQ]` - see **@Thies Heidecke**'s answer).

Even though, such an approach allows for numeric input only, such a wrapper does not provide any additional advantage. Consider the folowing definition:

```
g[y_?NumericQ] := h[x /. x -> y]
```

Indeed, now `x` will be 'forced' to take numeric values (the definition of `g` does not allow symbolic inputs). Also, `h` will be sure to operate on numeric input. The same result could have been achieved with somethng analogous to `f[ a / 2 /. a -> 1.]` from the example above.

My original answer was not lightning-fast and the other answer by **@Thies Heidecke** reported similar issues (especially for `n=200`) and also insightfully noted in the comments that the time constraints on the problem are imposed by the run-time of `Eigenvalues[]` function.

The present edit aims to present a solution with more acceptable time contraints. To that extent I opted for compiling and memoizing the input expressions. Also, I compiled the process of calculating the eigenvalues of `H` (also compiled) in order to take advantage of `RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}`. The code can be found [HERE](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/TWLY2ah6).

The following graphs display the values of `k` I tested my code on, along with the time it took to produce the output plot.

[image: GRAPH 1]

(I am using the `PlotStyle` parameters used in the answer by **@Thies Heidecke**)

It fails to produce the artifacts that are present in the other solution. This has to do perhaps with the fact that I am sampling parameter `k` in discrete, non-necessarily integer, intervals. Note, how the new code makes use of `Array[]` to sample `k`  `energies[pts_,lo_,hi_]:=Transpose[eigenvals[Array[#&,pts,{lo,hi}]//N]]`

The next graph plots pairs of `{k,time}` (in minutes, on my machine).

[image: GRAPH 2]

It appears that the `energies` scale linearly with the number of points we choose to sample `k`.

### original answer :

This is what I tried : n = 200;

mat1[a_, n_] := Array[E^(I a (#1 - 1)) KroneckerDelta[#1, #2] &, {n, n}]
mat2[a_, n_] := Array[E^(-I a (#1 - 1)) KroneckerDelta[#1, #2] &, {n, n}]

mat3[n_] := Array[KroneckerDelta[#1 - 1, #2] &, {n, n}]
mat4[n_] := Array[KroneckerDelta[#1 + 1, #2] &, {n, n}]

sigmap = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}};
sigmam = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}};

Hfunc = Function[{k, a, n}, KroneckerProduct[mat1[a, n], sigmap] + KroneckerProduct[mat2[a, n], sigmam] + E^(I k a) KroneckerProduct[mat2[a, n], sigmap] + E^(-I k a) KroneckerProduct[mat1[a, n], sigmam] + KroneckerProduct[mat3[n], sigmap] + KroneckerProduct[mat4[n], sigmam]];

H = Function[{k}, Hfunc[k, Pi/701., n]];

energies = Compile[{{k, *Real}}, Eigenvalues[H[k]], {{*, _Real, 1}}]

ListPlot[Array[energies[#] &, 10, {0, 2}] // Transpose, Joined -> True]

I tried using `SparseArray` but*Mathematica*complained :

> Eigenvalues::arh : Because finding 400 out of the 400 eigenvalues
>   and/or eigenvectors is likely to be faster with dense matrix methods,
>   the sparse input matrix will be converted.If fewer eigenvalues and/or
>   eigenvectors would be sufficient, consider restricting this number
>   using the second argument to Eigenvalues. >>

Comment: How fast is it?

Comment: ~19secs on my machine

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 200;
mat1 = Table[E^(I \[Alpha] (x - 1)) KroneckerDelta[x, y], {x, 1, n}, {y, 1, n}];
mat2 = Table[E^(-I \[Alpha] (x - 1)) KroneckerDelta[x, y], {x, 1, n}, {y, 1, n}];
mat3 = Table[KroneckerDelta[x - 1, y], {x, 1, n}, {y, 1, n}];
mat4 = Table[KroneckerDelta[x + 1, y], {x, 1, n}, {y, 1, n}];
sigmap = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}};
sigmam = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}};

H = KroneckerProduct[mat1, sigmap] + KroneckerProduct[mat2, sigmam] + E^(I k \[Alpha]) KroneckerProduct[mat2, sigmap] + E^(-I k \[Alpha]) KroneckerProduct[mat1, sigmam] + KroneckerProduct[mat3, sigmap] + KroneckerProduct[mat4, sigmam];
MyEigenvalues[kk_?NumericQ] := Sort@Eigenvalues[H /. {\[Alpha] -> Pi/701., k -> kk}]

(g = With[{maxk=2},ListLinePlot[Transpose@Table[MyEigenvalues[k], {k, 0, maxk}], DataRange -> {0, maxk}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.15], Blue]]]) //Timing
```

gives a computation time of 1.19s for the `g` part on my machine (2010 MBP).

Now increasing the maximum `k` from `2` to `1000`

```
(data = With[{maxk = 1000}, Transpose@Table[MyEigenvalues[k], {k, 0, maxk}]];) // Timing
(g = With[{maxk = 1000}, ListLinePlot[data, DataRange -> {0, maxk}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.15], Blue]]]) // Timing
```

gives me 241s and 4s for the computation of `data` and the plot `g` respectively, and produces this plot:

[image: Eigenvalue plot for k=0..1000]

I didn't manage to get rid of the artifacts at the multiples of 100, but i think the plot still comes out nice. If anyone has an idea how to get rid of the artifacts, i'm happy to hear and improve the answer.

Comment: your code takes ~2.9secs on my machine (just for reference)

Comment: Thanks! it is very helpful. what part of your code made the difference?

Comment: @UP_TLV: Glad that it's helpful to your understanding of Mathematica and to your application! I think the key is the `MyEigenvalues` function with the `NumericQ` pattern, which makes sure that `Eigenvalues` always solves numerical eigenvalue problems and never symbolic ones.